# HTML validation errors

Tags: html

I need to understand this code, when I put this on the revalidation site of W3Schools, it says that I have 3 errors and warnings.
Where is the problem: I don't understand why it says that the  is not finished.

```
<html>


<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="center"> 

<table width="580" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
           <td class="permission" align="center">
              <p>You're receiving this newsletter because you have subscribed to us.</p>
              <p> If you would like to submit information, email us at mail@mail.com with the subject line "INFORMATION".</p>

           </td> </tr>   

 </table>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most serious error is that there are no `head`, `title` or `body` tags. These are required for your document to be valid.

The base of a HTML document should be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, you should really have a [DocType](http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-doctype) and declare your [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/#Slide0250).

Here's the "complete" basic template for XHTML 1.0 Strict, delivered as HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>...</title>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the input will try to edit it again and I'll see  if it works. cheers